# For Loop returning strange length

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this javascript code:

```js
var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
  key = '',
  c;

for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  c = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length + 1);
  key += chars.charAt(c)
}

console.log('return key length that needs to be 32...' + key.length);
```

I need to always return 32 key length..but i get random:

```
return key length that needs to be 32...31
return key length that needs to be 32...29
return key length that needs to be 32...32
return key length that needs to be 32...31
return key length that needs to be 32...30
return key length that needs to be 32...32
return key length that needs to be 32...31
```

I know that error is in: `i<32;` but javascript freezes when i add `i=32;` i try `i<=32` but same results...so i know it is basic question but i don't know hot to return always 32 key length?

Comment: Get rid of `+ 1`.

Comment: "_javascript freezes when i add i=32; i try i<=32 but same results_" Instead of just blindly guessing what to change you should use your debugger to step through the code and see where exactly it does something you don't expect and then go from there.

Comment: how about `i<33`

Comment: why don't you simply do `chars.length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here `Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length + 1);`

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1, inclusive. When it's 1 then `Math.floor(1 * 32 + 1)` gives `33` `chars.charAt(33)` is `undefined` though and results in nothing being added to `key` hence the random lengths.

Remove the `+ 1` and it should work as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `+ 1` in this line:

```
c = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length + 1);
```

Valid indexes run from `0` to `chars.length-1`. The above assignment picks a random number from `1` to `chars.length`. So it ignores the first character in the string, and sometimes tries to access outside the string. In the latter case it `chars.charAt(c)` returns `undefined`, and appending that doesn't add to the length of the result.

```js
var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
  key = '',
  c;

for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  c = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  key += chars.charAt(c)
}

console.log('return key length that needs to be 32...' + key.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
        key   = '',
        c;

    for (i=0;i<32;i++) {
        c = Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length);
        key += chars.charAt(c);
    }

    console.log('return key length that needs to be 32...'+key.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes math.random() return such value (Math.random() * chars.length + 1) becomes >= 64.

```
Math.random()*char.length+1 >= 64
Math.random()*char.length >= 63
Math.random()* >= 63/64 (in our case)
Math.random() >= 0.984375
```

If math.random returns value >= 0.984375 then c will be get 64 so length of key will be less than 32. 
You don't need to add 1 to solve this problem.